# Setting model for textarea - return null when submiting

Tags: java, wicket

So i have little issue with wicket (i'm new to this one). So here's my TextArea method

TextArea.java

```
public class TextArea extends org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextArea<String>{
    public TextArea(String id, int maxLength, PageMode...visibleModes) {
        this(id, null, visibleModes);
        add(StringValidator.maximumLength(maxLength));
    }       
}
```

That I'm calling here

```
noteTemplate = new TextArea(NoteTemplatePanel.noteTemplate", 1024, PageMode.EDIT);
```

Then I'm tryin to fill my textarea with default value (I want to fill textarea with text). So I'm using somethink like this:

```
IModel<String> oldNoteTemplate = Model.of("test");
noteTemplate.setModel(oldNoteTemplate)
```

This is my HTML side of it:

```
    [...]
 <td width="50%" class="editPanelRow">  
  <textarea wicket:id="NoteTemplatePanel.noteTemplate" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
 </td>
    [...]
```

So here it goes: without this code above where I add model everythink works fine, but when I have added this code, textarea was filling just like it should but when I'm saving this, instead of text thats inside i get null. Someone know the answer? If you need more code please let me know but I think it's enough (and sorry for my bad english).

Also in class where I create Textarea I'm using this:

```
@Getter
private Form<noteTemplateBean> form;

@Data
class noteTemplateBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3498931024241308433L;

    private String noteTemplate;

}
```

and that noteTemplate become null (noteTemplateBean.getNoteTemplate()).

Comment: Why the javascript tag?

Comment: Does the textarea's model become null or does the model's content become null? The parent class of `TextArea` (`AbstractTextComponent`) has the method `setConvertEmptyInputStringToNull` which might be related.

Comment: I think model's content become null. I have added code and explained what becomes null so check it cause I might be wrong.